# Use higher precision than needed when computing a sum

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

Is it a good practice to use larger precision when computing a sum and reduce the precision at the end of the algorithm? Like

```
float average(const float* begin, const float* end)
    {
    double sum=0;
    size_t N=end-begin;
    while(begin!=end)
        {
        sum+=(double)(*begin);
        ++begin;
        }

    return (float)( sum/N); //Assume range is not empty
    }
```

It may be, because there are less errors in the accumulation. On the other hand things can go wrong when converting between the data types.

Comment: In C, all floating-point arithmetic is in `double`-precision *anyway*. `float` is for storage only.

Comment: @EOF His point is that the intermediate sum is being stored at a higher precision.

Comment: @EOF: That was in the very first C version. In current versions, it depends on the compiler, but usually arithmetic involving float will be done using float precision.

Comment: Well your method is interesting but using large precision variables will obviously decrease the program performance. Anyways I have a happy side towards your idea.

Comment: @AnishSharma Depending on the compiler and the architecture, storing as `double` may in fact increase performance.

Comment: @AnishSharma: Using larger precision does not always decrease the performance of the program.  This depends on what the target processor can do and if the values must be moved across a memory bus that's smaller than they are very often.  Many processors would rather work on 64 bit floating point values than 32 bit.

Comment: I must appreciate your help. I am a novice student in CS so I might not have the best idea. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: @EOF: Even if the compiler and processor are doing higher or highest precision arithmetic, you have to watch out for storing and accessing intermediary values to a low(er) precision type.  `float x = A + B + C;` could have a different result than `float x = 0; x += A; x+= B; x+= C;` since in the second the values are likely to be truncated so that the result would be the same as if the statements were in separate functions.

Comment: @user877329: If you want the most accurate summation of floating point values use the largest accumulator (the `sum` variable in your code), sort the values by magnatude from least to greatest, and add them in that order.  This will give the little values the opportunity to add together in to form higher values before they lose precision due to any rounding that takes place when the processor is adding them to values with a different exponent (the decimal point is in a different place).

Comment: @EOF: C11 6.3.1.8: Float will not necessarily be converted to double, but the compiler may.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to avoid, but probably not.

If you're trying to avoid catastrophic cancellation (where `10^100 + 1 - 10^100` results in 0 instead of 1), using a wider FP type will help a little bit but not very much.

If the numbers are a lot closer together in magnitude, but you're still worried about LSBs falling off the end as the sum grows (e.g. `1e-8 + 1e-8 + (1e8 copies) != 1`), the wider type *can* help, but again, only up to a point.

What *really* helps is cleverer methods of floating point summation. The easiest method is known as "pairwise summation", where you view your array of numbers as the leaves of a binary tree, and recursively sum pairs of them until you're left with only one number. For iterative summation as you're doing there, you can also sort the numbers first, which tends to decrease the error. And there are more complex, and more exact methods available... google "compensated summation" for details.

All of which is to say, if you suspect that rounding errors are going to be a problem for you, `double sum` is helpful, but is probably not going to be enough.

Oh, and with regards to "things can go wrong when converting between the data types": Things *can* go wrong (in particular, double-rounding errors), but the imprecision you're likely to see from them is not significant compared to the error from performing the summation itself.

Comment: It would be interesting with a quantification of "not very much" assuming random numbers from some distribution

Comment: @user877329 The difference in exponent at which a particular level of cancellation occurs is given by the mantissa size. That is, with `float` intermediate results, `1 + ~6e-8 - 1` is on the edge of cancelling to zero, while with `double` intermediate results, `1 + ~1e-16 - 1` is.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that *isn't* good practice is reducing the precision at the end.

Anyway, your code is dividing by zero, because when you do the division, begin == end.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't: doing this sort of thing further ties your implementation to a particular platform. There's no guarantee in C that as `float` is less precise than a `double`, and a precision reduction at the end is not good practice and not particularly cheap computationally speaking either.

I'd leave the compiler to do its job.

When adding numbers though in floating point, it's a good idea to accumulate the smaller magnitude numbers first. Then they stand a better chance of contributing to the sum. There are more advanced floating point summation methods; you should consider them too.

Comment: In both hardware and software implementations, converting between `float` and `double` is one of the cheapest FP operations you can do.

Comment: Houses are cheaper in Marylebone than Mayfair but I still wouldn't buy one. Btw, loved your answer - plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Sneftel mentioned methods of summation. Here are a set of functions that work with an array of 2048 IEEE 64 bit doubles (passed by the caller). (Assumes that unsigned long long is also 64 bits) .

```
/* clear array */
void clearsum(double asum[2048])
{
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        asum[i] = 0.;
}

/* add a number into array */
void addtosum(double d, double asum[2048])
{
size_t i;
    while(1){
        /* i = exponent of d */
        i = ((size_t)((*(unsigned long long *)&d)>>52))&0x7ff;
        if(i == 0x7ff){         /* max exponent, could be overflow */
            asum[i] += d;
            return;
        }
        if(asum[i] == 0.){      /* if empty slot store d */
            asum[i] = d;
            return;
        }
        d += asum[i];           /* else add slot to d, clear slot */
        asum[i] = 0.;           /* and continue until empty slot */
    }
}

/* return sum from array */
double returnsum(double asum[2048])
{
double sum = 0.;
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        sum += asum[i];
    return sum;
}
```